# Word Request: a word that means "taken over a long span of time"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm hoping that this request makes sense -

For the past 14 years of my life I've half-written a story that goes on in my head. I've always struggled for a name to call it, but have recently taken to referring to it as "The Anthology," mostly because in my head "anthology" relates to a story that takes place over a large period of time. I decided to look up anthology, and it doesn't *exactly* mean what it connotes to me. I've tried a few google searches and a search on here, but no luck -- is there such a word?

To give a hint at the span of time I'm referring to, the story starts about 14,000 years ago and ends far off into the future.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. If there is a word in another language that is close, I would love to hear it (and which language it comes from)

Comment: "Saga" is sometimes used for long-span, involved narratives. It might connote old northern epics but actually I've remembered it now in connection to The Forsyte Saga.

Comment: @anemone - With one or two references included, that would be a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Saga](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saga) is sometimes used for long-span, involved narratives. It might connote old northern epics but I've remembered it now in connection with [The Forsyte Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forsyte_Saga) (which tells a story of a large family through several generations in late 19th/early 20th century, London).

Also, looking up this word might bring in more suggestions.

Comment: Epic is also a term for a story that takes place over a long period of time too!

Comment: @Araucaria thank you :) indeed my remark was superfluous. I was merely trying to say that was the word I might have used were it my own story, but the OP might go for another one, and 'saga' might be a better start than 'anthology'.

Comment: I was just thinking that you might want to add that in as part of your answer! :-) Oh yes, forget, +1!